# Why doesn't UglifyJS mangle certain properties?

Tags: uglifyjs

Why does UglifyJS not mangle certain properties, even if I explicitly ask it to do so? In particular, it does not mangle `test`, `action`, `type`, `types`, `text`.

```
> type tmp.js
var a;
a = { foo: 1 };
a = { test: 1 };
a = { tests: 1 };
a = { action: 1};
a = { actions: 1 };
a = { type: 1 };
a = { types: 1 };
a = { text: 1 };
a = { texts: 1 };

> uglifyjs --version
uglify-js 3.3.6

> uglifyjs tmp.js -m --mangle-props
var a;a={t:1};a={test:1};a={s:1};a={action:1};a={o:1};a={type:1};a={types:1};a={text:1};a={i:1};

> uglifyjs tmp.js -m --mangle-props regex="/^foo$/"
var a;a={t:1};a={test:1};a={tests:1};a={action:1};a={actions:1};a={type:1};a={types:1};a={text:1};a={texts:1};

> uglifyjs tmp.js -m --mangle-props regex="/^(foo|test|tests|action|actions|type|types|text|texts)$/"
var a;a={t:1};a={test:1};a={s:1};a={action:1};a={o:1};a={type:1};a={types:1};a={text:1};a={i:1};
```

Comment: uglify (and now terser) use a whitelist of terms that are not to be mangled. This behaviour can be overriden if so desired.